# Why does an electric field not blur together the Landau levels?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, condensed-matter, electrons, quantum-hall-effect

When a crossed electric field $E$ is applied on top of a magnetic field $B$, one can show that the degeneracy of the Landau levels is lifted, such as in these [David Tong notes](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/qhe.html). Intuitively it feels like this should blur together the Landau levels if $eEL > \hbar\omega_B$, where $L$ is the length of the system and $\omega_B=\frac{eB}{m}$ is the cyclotron frequency, in which case phenomena such as the quantum hall effect should disappear.

Is this intuition correct or not? Are we just typically in a regime where the levels are still nicely separated, and what sorts of values would these quantities take in an experiment?

Comment: Is $L$ the length of the system parallel to the direction of $E$ or perpendicular to it?

Comment: Parallel to it, so $eEL$ is the potential energy across the length $L$

Answer (score 0):

The problem of Landau level electrons in an external electric field is conveniently solved in the Landau gauge (see sec. 1.4.2, in Tong's lecture notes). The energy of a LL is modified as $\epsilon_{n,k}=\epsilon_{n,k}^0 -eEl_B^2k -e^2E^2/2m_e\omega_c^2$, where $\epsilon_{n,k}^0$ is the energy for no electric field, and $k$ is the wavenumber for $y$ direction (LL wavefunctions are plane waves along $y$ in the Landau gauge). This shows that the $E$ field uniformly shifts the energy spectrum for each $n$, which means there is no intermixing of Landau levels (see Fig in sec. 1.4.2 in Tong).

Comment: What I mean is that the Landau levels can overlap in energy at different values of $k$ (c.f. the lines of Figure 5 in section 1.4.2. and imagine they are steeper). Then it would seem that transitions can occur between Landau levels without energy cost.

Comment: Yes, it seems so. But then again, wavefunctions at different $k$ are localized at different $x_k=x_0-kl_B^2$, so the probability that an electron from one end of the spectrum will transition to the other end is small.

Comment: Makes sense. But if states are filled in order of increasing energy, the next Landau level should start being filled before the previous one is full, and the QHE should disappear right?

Comment: Yes, QHE disappears if there is no 'gap' between Landau levels. Your situation is similar to pre-QH regime where we have Subhnikov-de Haas oscillations. There, LL broadening is due to disorder rather than electric field, but I believe the effect is the same.

Comment: Good, if you add these comments to your answer I can accept it